# Linux system updates one-by-one or at once

Tags: linux, updates

I am using Fedora 36. I use KDE's Discover to find and install updates. It requires restart.

Suppose there were 7 system updates made available in a week. And I didn't update the system entire week and decided to update on the last day.

- Will it download and install only the latest update?
- Or it'll download and install all 7 updates one by one with 7 restarts?
- What will happen if I do update from terminal `sudo dnf upgrade`? does it behave the same?

What would be the good practice if I want to update only on weekends?

---

Things I've tried so far:

- I didn't update for a few days and today I had to restart twice using Discover till it stopped giving update available message.
- I haven't tried `sudo dnf upgrade`. I have no idea how it differs.

Note: Linux is new to me so I may not know obvious tings.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Toto I've updated the answer. I have no spare machine to experiment with so I am being cautious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will it download and install only the latest update?
> Or it'll download and install all 7 updates one by one with 7 restarts?

Both, and neither, as those 7 updates apply to different components – i.e. you have 7 separate packages in `dnf` waiting for upgrade. They *all* are the "latest update", and they all will be installed at the same time.

Updates in Linux are linear. If several new versions of the same package are issued over the week (e.g. due to last-minute changes), this will only count as 1 "update", as you will always upgrade directly to the latest version of every package. Overlapping updates (i.e. independent updates that patch different changes into the same component) are not done in Linux.

Only one reboot should be enough to install all updates. The reboot is not actually necessary to perform the package upgrades; the reboot is there to avoid weird things from happening to your running apps *after* (or during) the upgrade.

(For example, if you open an app while one of its required libraries is being upgraded, it might crash, or it might load halfway – plugins missing, icons missing. Fedora has moved from traditional "online" updating to the reboot-based update method primarily to avoid this kind of glitches. Take a look at the [design notes](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Desktop/Whiteboards/UpdateExperience).

More importantly, if a critical security fix in e.g. OpenSSL or some other library is released, it won't magically apply to processes that still have the old version of that library loaded into memory – they all have to be restarted, and it's easier and more reliable to just do a full reboot.)

At least currently, as far as I know, the actual installation stage of "reboot to install" just ends up running more or less the same `dnf upgrade` and will update all packages at once, the only difference is that it'll be done while none of your apps are running.

So you *could* use `dnf upgrade` directly, but you should at least wait until it finishes before continuing with your work – and if you see libraries being updated you *should* restart apps that use them... assuming you can keep track of which apps need what, which is why Fedora just tells users to reboot instead. The proper way to run "reboot to install" from CLI would be `dnf offline-upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! `Updates in Linux are linear. Overlapping updates are not done in Linux.` I was looking for exactly this. I do not see `offline-upgrade` option for dnf on my system. Considering [this dicussion](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6585881), for updates during reboot, I'll stick to updates using KDE's `Discover` or GNOME's `Software`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't necessarily apply to the system as a whole (at least on traditional Linux distributions), it is more about packages themselves. Each individual package is updated linearly, but it _is_ technically possible to upgrade some packages first, others later, resulting in overall non-linear update of the system (although this is usually *very much discouraged* as it would often lead to incompatibilities and all kinds of breakage, I only mention it as "technically possible").